# SIGABRT Error When I Sending Data to Kinvey

Tags: database, swift, kinvey

Why does my data is not send to the Kinvey backend? My app keeps crashing and I get the `SIGABRT` error. I have tried changing the `String` to `NSString` but that didn't help. For some reason, my dashboard in Kinvey does show API Calls and Data storage but it's not storing anything (I am a beginner).

```
import UIKit

class ReservationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userSeat: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userDateTime: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func sendReservation(sender: AnyObject) {
        // STORE DATA
        let store = KCSAppdataStore.storeWithOptions([
            KCSStoreKeyCollectionName : "userReservation",
            KCSStoreKeyCollectionTemplateClass : Booking.self
        ])
        let reservation = Booking()
        reservation.name = userName.text
        reservation.email = userEmail.text
        reservation.seats = userSeat.text
        reservation.date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1352149171) //sample date
        store.saveObject(
            reservation,
            withCompletionBlock: { (objectsOrNil: [AnyObject]!, errorOrNil: NSError!) -> Void in
                if errorOrNil != nil {
                    //save failed
                    NSLog("Save failed, with error: %@", errorOrNil.localizedFailureReason!)
                } else {
                    //save was successful
                    NSLog("Successfully saved event (id='%@').", (objectsOrNil[0] as! NSObject).kinveyObjectId())
                }
            },
            withProgressBlock: nil
        )
    }

    class Booking : NSObject {    //all NSObjects in Kinvey implicitly implement KCSPersistable
        var entityId: String? //Kinvey entity _id
        var name: NSString?
        var email: NSString?
        var seats: NSString?
        var date: NSDate?

    }

    override func hostToKinveyPropertyMapping() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]! {
        return [
            "entityId" : KCSEntityKeyId, //the required _id field
            "name" : "name",
            "email" : "email",
            "seats" : "seats",
            "date" : "date",
        ]
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is actually your code and not just a mistake you made when copy-pasting, the problem is that your `Booking` class is currently a nested class in your `ReservationViewController`, and you implemented `hostToKinveyPropertyMapping` as a method of `ReservationViewController`.

Instead, create a new file for your Kinvey class:

```
class Booking: NSObject {
    var entityId: String? //Kinvey entity _id
    var name: NSString?
    var email: NSString?
    var seats: NSString?
    var date: NSDate?

    override func hostToKinveyPropertyMapping() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]! {
        return [
            "entityId" : KCSEntityKeyId, //the required _id field
            "name": "name",
            "email": "email",
            "seats": "seats",
            "date": "date"  //You also had an extra comma after the last item of this dictionary.
        ]
    }
}
```

And delete that code from your view controller. Also, make sure you safely unwrap all optional values, and confirm that your collection really is named "userReservation".

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner i have been on vacation for the past 3 weeks I will test this as soon as i come back this week!, I am still a little confused by what you mean by creating a new file?

Comment: No problem, I was just joking! I meant you should add a new Swift file to your XCode project, and put the code for the Booking class there, just to clearly separate it from your ReservationViewController. I think they should be two completely separate classes.

Comment: How do I call upon the code if it is in a new class and not connected to the reservation view controller? Im sorry kinda new to this...

Comment: You do it the same way you're doing it now: `let booking = Booking()`, and then you can manipulate your booking object as you wish. It's common practice when working in an IDE like Xcode to create a separate file for each class.